# Combo box isn't filling from DB table that is different than the datagridview data source

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview in my application that has its DataSource set to pull from the MemberInfo table in my DB:

```
m_DataAdapt = New SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM memberInfo ORDER BY lName ASC", m_DBConn)
m_CommBuild = New SqlCommandBuilder(m_DataAdapt)
m_DataSet = New DataSet()
m_DataAdapt.Fill(m_DataSet)

dgvMemberInfo.AutoGenerateColumns = False
dgvMemberInfo.DataSource = m_DataSet.Tables("Table")
```

This works as expected and gives me all the correct columns. However I want the Rank and Role columns to be combo boxes that get their options from a different table in the DB:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ3WQ.jpg

However when I run the application and choose the drop downs, they are empty and there are no errors thrown. As far as I've seen so far this should work. Is there a setting/code line somewhere else that I have to do?

Comment: Where's the code that fills the ComboBoxes? It looks like you're referencing a BindingSource in some way...

Comment: I did not write any code to fill the ComboBoxes, only used the Designer to set it as seen in the image. The guides I found said that would pull in the content of that table and have a value in the dropdown for every value of rankName in the table.

Comment: Which DataTable? Nobody can see what is the DataSource of those ComboBoxes. Check that out and you'll probably find the *source* of the problem.

Comment: The datagridview gets its data from the memberInfo DB table. The rank ComboBox has its DataSource set in the Designer to be AvailRanksBindingSource like the picture shows. That table exists in the DB, has my testing data in it properly, and I can access all the rows fine if I wanted to print them to a message box. 
Is there more that has to be done in code or in the Designer to get this to bring in the ranks properly?

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, setting it in the Designer did nothing, but setting the same stuff through code worked:

```
Dim b_rankAdapt As SqlDataAdapter
b_rankAdapt = New SqlDataAdapter("Select * From availRanks", m_DBConn)
Dim dt As DataTable
dt = New DataTable
b_rankAdapt.Fill(dt)

For Each iRow As DataGridViewRow In dgvMemberInfo.Rows
    RankDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataSource = dt
    RankDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ValueMember = "rankID"
    RankDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DisplayMember = "rankName"
Next
```

I didn't try this before because I didn't know I could reference the cell directly through `RankDataGridViewTextBoxColumn`.